# Error while installing rspec gem bignum too big to convert into `long'

Tags: rspec, cucumber, rubygems, bignum

I was recently trying to change the version of rspec I installed from -v 2.5.0 to 1.3.0 to work with rails 2.x. After uninstalling cucumber, rspec-rails, and rspec I went to reinstall and then recieved the error "ERROR:  While executing gem ... (RangeError) bignum too big to convert into `long' . I tried installing the other gems rspec-rails and cucumber but they are now giving me this error as well. Even when I try to install the rspec -v 2.5.0 which was installed before I get the same error. I can install other gems fine. I only get the error when I try to install gems that are associated with rspec (rspec, rspec-rails and cucumber). This is a real pain because I need to run some cucumber tests for my rails application. Any insight appreciated.
- Adam

Answer (score 2):

You need to upgrade to ruby-1.8.7-p248 at least to have a guarantee to fix it (upgrading rubygems won't work).

More details on http://revision-zero.org/history-of-a-bug